# Creating 'Open file alert' for calendar event in applescript

Tags: applescript, icalendar

I'm having some trouble creating calendar appointments with 'open file' alerts from applescript.  Creating the event is not an issue, however, I can't get the open file alert bit to work.  I'm sure I'm missing something stupid but any help would be appreciated...

```
set resultTime to time string of date ("09:45" as string)

set startTime to (date (resultTime)) + (1 * days)
set endTime to startTime

set alertPath to (POSIX path of (path to home folder as string)) & "Documents/TestScript.app"

tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Test Calendar"
        make new event with properties {summary:"Start Script", start date:startTime, end date:endTime}
        set calEvent to the result
        tell calEvent
            make new display alarm at end with properties {trigger interval:0}
            make new display alarm at end with properties {trigger interval:-15}

            make new open file alarm at end with properties {trigger interval:-15, filepath:alertPath}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I've temporarily put in a few display alarms to check that I could create them, which works so it is just the `'make new open file alarm ...'` line.  The variable `resultTime` comes from earlier in the final script, however, I've cut that all out while testing it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Adding new `open file alarm`s doesn't seem to work in modern Calendar, if it ever did. I got it to work once about 5 minutes ago for `/Applications/Calendar.app`, but now it won't even do that. Regardless, Calendar's scripting support seems, given the state of its dictionary, like a half-baked feature that was just brought over from the old iCal in whatever condition it was in. So, I'm really not surprised by these difficulties.

Comment: If you wanted to be absurdly hacky, you could add a `mail alarm` (which I also tested and have found to work), then use an Apple Mail rule that detects your email and opens the file. Or you could just use some system scheduling service other than Calendar if you need such advanced features as automatic on-demand event creation. You could try using `launchd`; I have never used it myself, but I know it's what Apple generally recommends for server-grade task scheduling.